# Docker UCP Setup - Cannot Connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-ucp

I am trying to setup Docker UCP and using the below command

## docker container run --rm -it --name ucp -v /var/run/docker/sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/ucp:2.2.4 install --host-address 172.31.22.77 --interactive

This command is run under the username "user" and "user" is part of docker group. /var/run/docker.sock is owned by root and the group owner is docker. "user" is part of docker group. I am able to pull any images(hello-world) and run them in container without any problem. But when i try to setup UCP, i get the below error :

INFO[0000] Verifying your system is compatible with UCP 2.2.4 (168ec746e)

FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Can anyone help me with this, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your command, you mounted `docker/sock` instead of `docker.sock`:

```
docker container run --rm -it --name ucp \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  docker/ucp:2.2.4 install --host-address 172.31.22.77 --interactive
```